# How to identify a long press on arrow keys in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keydown

I have two options to myself `keypress` and `keydown`. I am inclined to use `keypress` because it records an event, even if the key is repeated i.e. key is long pressed. But the problem is that `keypress` records special keys such as arrow keys only in Firefox. If I want to do it cross browser then I have to use `keydown` but then a long press will be recorded as a single event.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was reading somewhere keydown is better suited for this than, keyup but I think in my case any one would work the same

Comment: You can read about all this stuff here: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html.

Answer (score 9):

```
var pressed = null;
$(element).on('keydown', function(event) {
    pressed = +new Date();
    // do whatever else you need upon key down
});
$(element).on('keyup', function(event) {
    var duration = +new Date() - pressed;
    pressed = null;
    // do whatever you need to do based on the duration of the press
});
```

I leave it as an exercise to you to work out support for multiple concurrent keys pressed.

Comment: Your code won't work. You have to store the keyCode to be sure the keyup is associate to the keydown.

Comment: @DieVarDump you apparently missed the line under the code snippet.

Comment: @Derek please stop editing my response with wrong suggestions.

Comment: `new Date()` returns a Date instance. `Date.now()` returns milliseconds since epoch. Since we're calculating a duration it makes no sense to go through full date instances.

Comment: I don't think multiple concurrent keypress would be an issue, however there is one thing, what is the relation between the duration of key press and number position the cursor moves in that duration

Comment: jQuery event object has very useful property for that purposes: [event.timeStamp](http://api.jquery.com/event.timeStamp/).

Comment: Agree with @Derek, what's the point in using `Date.now()` when it doesn't work in all browsers and is hardly any less typing than `+new Date`. `+new Date` **does not** return a new date instance, in fact, the way to shim `Date.now()` is `+new Date()` as suggested here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#Cross-browser_compatibility

Comment: @lanzz yes I apparently missed it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Derek, Esailija: JS 1.5 has been released twelve years ago. I had no idea IE has not supported it for more than ten years after its release.

Comment: @lanzz what are you talking about? `Date.now()` is a recent addition. It wasn't even in google chrome until version 5

Comment: @Esailija according to MDN, Date.now() is part of JS 1.5, which according to wikipedia has been released November 2000.

Comment: @lanzz No, according to MDN, it's part of ecmascript edition 5, which was published in 2009

Answer (score 3):

You could use two events, like so:

```
var timer=false,
    pressedTime = 1000; //one second

$('input').on({
    keydown: function(e) {
        var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode, keyP;
        if (charCode===37) keyP = 'left';
        if (charCode===38) keyP = 'up';
        if (charCode===39) keyP = 'right';
        if (charCode===40) keyP = 'down';        
        if (!timer) timer = setTimeout(function() {
           clearTimeout(timer);
           timer=false;
           alert(keyP+' arrow key held down for 1 second');
        }, pressedTime);
    },
    keyup: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer=false;
    }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/B2rmk/1/)

Comment: @Ghokun - Thanks, seems the easiest way to do it, and it should avoid long arguments over time objects in JS.

Answer (score 0):

there's a plugin named [jQuery Responsiveness](http://programmingdrunk.com/current-projects/jquery.responsiveness/) which may help achieving this.

Comment: No that would not help. What I am trying to do is to copying all keyboard actions of a user into another text box as it is. Responsiveness would be more useful to reduce the number of calls I make for copying the actions. I might factor this thing later once I have a basic version running